# load json with reactjs

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I'll be very grateful who can help me with this line
I've this:

```
 var Country = React.createClass({
        render:function(){
            return(
                <nav> 
                <h2>list of country:</h2>
                { this.props.country}
                </nav>
            )
        }
    }) 
    var Jugador =React.createClass({
          componentWillMount: function(){
                var pais;
                var self = this;
                $.getJSON("https://restcountries.eu/rest/v1/all", function(data){
                    for(pais in data)
                    {
                        console.log(pais, data[pais].name);

                        return(
                            <Country key={i} country={self.render(data[pais].name)}> </Country>
                        )
                    }
                })
          },
    })
```

and it does not work, and appear this error
Uncaught Invariant Violation: createClass(...): Class specification must implement a `render` method.

Comment: Jugador doesn't have a render method. Is it a react component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In React each component must have `render` method, you should implement it. I've refactored your code and now it look like this

```
var Country = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return <div> 
      { this.props.country }
    </div>
  }
})

var Countries = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function () {
    return { countries: [] };
  },

  componentWillMount: function(){
    $.getJSON("https://restcountries.eu/rest/v1/all", function (data) {
      this.setState({ countries: data })
    }.bind(this))
  },

  render: function () {
    var countries = this.state.countries.map(function (el, i) {
      return <Country key={i} country={ el.name } />
    }, this);

    return <nav>
      <h2>list of country:</h2>
      <div>{ countries }</div>
    </nav>;
  }       
})
```

[`Example`](https://jsfiddle.net/_alexander_/69z2wepo/34671/)

Answer (score 1):

Your `Jugador` component needs to implement a `render` method.